# Using paste0, get, and for loop to name multiple columns and apply functions

Tags: r

Here is what my data looks like:

(Number refer to different kinds of fruits; CT1_100_FQ, CT1_100_AM, CT1_100_SS are predetermined numbers)

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ExclusionTable)
library(lubridate)

totfr <- list('095',
              '096',
              '097',
              '098',
              '099',
              '100',
              '101',
              '102',
              '103',
              '104',
              '105',
              '106')

hgi <- list('096',
            '097',
            '099')
mgi <- list('100',
            '101',
            '105')
lgi <- list('095',
            '098',
            '102',
            '103',
            '104',
            '106')

hgl <- list('097',
            '099',
            '104',
            '105')
mgl <- list('096',
            '100')
lgl <- list('095',
            '098',
            '101',
            '102',
            '103',
            '106')

classification <- list(
                    totfr,
                    hgi,
                    mgi,
                    lgi,
                    hgl,
                    mgl,
                    lgl
                    )

names(classification) <- c(
                           "totfr",
                           "hgi",
                           "mgi",
                           "lgi",
                           "hgl",
                           "mgl",
                           "lgl"
                           )
```

This is my code

```
ct <-
  ct %>%
  for (i in 1:length(classification))
    for (j in 1:length(classification[[i]])){
                            get(paste("ct$CT1_F", classification[[i]][j], sep="")) <- get(paste("ct$CT1_F", paste0(classification[[i]][j], "_FQ"), sep="")[i])*paste("ct$CT1_F", paste0(classification[[i]][j], "_SS"), sep="")*paste("CT1_F", paste0(classification[[i]][j], "_AM"), sep="")
                            } %>%
  lapply(List, function(x) lapply(x, rowSums)) 
  for (i in 1:length(classification))
                paste("ct$CT1_", names(classification[i]), sep="") = rowSums(paste("ct$CT1_F", classification[[i]], sep=""), na.rm = T)
```

I want the result of my code to be the same as if I were to run the code below. Even after I use the function get(), it still doesn't work. get() returns characters only.

```
 #each columns belong to data.frame called ct. 
 ct$CT1_F095 = ct$CT1_F095_FQ*ct$CT1_F095_SS*ct$CT1_F095_AM,
 ct$CT1_F096 = ct$CT1_F096_FQ*ct$CT1_F096_SS*ct$CT1_F096_AM,
 ct$CT1_F097 = ct$CT1_F097_FQ*ct$CT1_F097_SS*ct$CT1_F097_AM,
 ct$CT1_F098 = ct$CT1_F098_FQ*ct$CT1_F098_SS*ct$CT1_F098_AM,
 ct$CT1_F099 = ct$CT1_F099_FQ*ct$CT1_F099_SS*ct$CT1_F099_AM,
 ct$CT1_F100 = ct$CT1_F100_FQ*ct$CT1_F100_SS*ct$CT1_F100_AM,
 ct$CT1_F101 = ct$CT1_F101_FQ*ct$CT1_F101_SS*ct$CT1_F101_AM,
 ct$CT1_F102 = ct$CT1_F102_FQ*ct$CT1_F102_SS*ct$CT1_F102_AM,
 ct$CT1_F103 = ct$CT1_F103_FQ*ct$CT1_F103_SS*ct$CT1_F103_AM,
 ct$CT1_F104 = ct$CT1_F104_FQ*ct$CT1_F104_SS*ct$CT1_F104_AM,
 ct$CT1_F105 = ct$CT1_F105_FQ*ct$CT1_F105_SS*ct$CT1_F105_AM,
 ct$CT1_F106 = ct$CT1_F106_FQ*ct$CT1_F106_SS*ct$CT1_F106_AM,
 ct$CT1_TOTFR = rowSums(pick(ct$CT1_F095:ct$CT1_F106), na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GI_L_F = rowSums(lgi, na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GI_M_F = rowSums(mgi, na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GI_H_F = rowSums(hgi, na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GL_L_F = rowSums(lgl, na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GL_M_F = rowSums(mgl, na.rm = T),
 ct$CT1_GL_H_F = rowSums(hgl, na.rm = T)
  )
```

```
paste("ct$CT1_F", classification[[1]], sep="")
```

returns

```
 [1] "ct$CT1_F095" "ct$CT1_F096" "ct$CT1_F097" "ct$CT1_F098" "ct$CT1_F099" "ct$CT1_F100"
 [7] "ct$CT1_F101" "ct$CT1_F102" "ct$CT1_F103" "ct$CT1_F104" "ct$CT1_F105" "ct$CT1_F106"
```

and

```
str(paste("ct$CT1_F", classification[[1]], sep=""))
```

returns

```
chr [1:12] "ct$CT1_F095" "ct$CT1_F096" "ct$CT1_F097" "ct$CT1_F098" "ct$CT1_F099" ...
```

when I type in manually,

```
>ct$CT1_F095
```

I get

```
>  [1]  7.00000000  1.75000000  0.75000000  3.50000000  0.75000000  1.75000000  3.50000000
   [8]  0.11627907  0.00000000  0.05813953  0.75000000  5.25000000  0.11627907  0.00000000
  [15]  0.75000000  1.75000000  1.75000000  0.29069767  0.37500000  2.62500000  0.37500000
  [22]  0.29069767  0.87500000  1.74418605  1.75000000  1.50000000  0.75000000  0.14534884
  [29]  1.12500000  2.75000000  0.75000000  1.75000000  3.50000000  0.05813953  4.12500000
  [36]  0.37500000  3.50000000  0.75000000  0.75000000  0.11627907  1.75000000  1.12500000
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 64608 entries ]
```

Comment: Given the code you provided, it is a bit difficult to follow what your inputs and desired outputs are. For example, how is ct defined? Are columns such as `ct$CT1_F095_FQ` already initialized or do you want to create them here? Try to break down the problem and give a more complete picture of the data you're working with.

Comment: Interesting you use all base R functions but not the new base R pipe, `|>`.

Comment: What is `pick`? Please post all `library` lines for [mre]. What is `List`. Also, do the `rowSums` in the longer code block work as written?

Comment: @degeso Thank you for the comments! I added library uses and ct$CT1_F095_FQ are already there.

Comment: @Parfait No I haven't checked the rowsum lines.

Comment: CT is the name of the cohort, CT1 is the cohort at time 1, CT2 is the same cohort at time 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using character vectors and split up `totfr` and `classification`. Then, run simple `for` loops to assign new columns in bulk given `paste0` is a vectorized method. Also, use `Reduce` to multiply multiple columns at once.

```r
totfr <- c(
  '095', '096', '097', '098', '099', '100', 
  '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106'
)

classification <- list(
  GI_L_F = c('095', '098','102', '103', '104', '106'),
  GI_M_F = c('100', '101', '105'),
  GI_H_F = c('096', '097', '099'),
  GL_L_F = c('095', '098', '101', '102', '103', '106'),
  GL_M_F = c('096', '100'),
  GL_H_F = c('097', '099', '104', '105')
)
```

```r
# INDIVIDUAL COLUMNS
for(col in totfr) {
  ct[paste0("CT1_F", col)] <- Reduce("*", ct[paste0("CT1_F", col, "_", c("FQ", "SS", "AM"))],
}
# TOTAL COLUMN
ct$CT1_TOTFR <- rowSums(ct[paste0("CT1_F", totfr)], nm.rm=TRUE)

# ROW SUMS
for(i in seq_along(classification)) {
  nm <- names(classification)[i]
  vals <- classification[[i]]
  ct[[paste0("CT1_", nm)]] <- rowSums(ct[paste0("CT1_F", vals)], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. the `nm` in ```ct[[paste0("CT1_", nm)]]``` should mean individual names of the list `classification` right?

Comment: Correct. I rewritten for proper variable assignment.